# How do I calculate the emission of co2 in all possible routes, instead of just one, like the code shows in line variable 'distance'

Tags: python, list, optimization

```py
def main():
    portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]

   
    D = [
            [0,8943,8019,3652,10545],
            [8943,0,2619,6317,2078],
            [8019,2619,0,5836,4939],
            [3652,6317,5836,0,7825],
            [10545,2078,4939,7825,0]
        ]

   
    co2 = 0.020

    route = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    distance =D[route[0]][route[1]] + D[route[1]][route[2]] + D[route[2]][route[3]] + D[route[3]][route[4]]
    emissions = distance * co2
    print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in route]) + " %.1f kg" % emissions)
    
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In what ways are you allowed to move?

You can do this with a queue, it would allow you to also change the size of the table without issue. Keep in mind complexity skyrockets with this method but you kinda need to test all paths. Please give more info on the way you can move in order for us to understand.

Comment: hey man ,so in this code when I play run , it just tell me one route PAn AMS  CAS NYC HEL , and then the amount of co2 in this route . Like you had said , I already tried , on another block of code (if you want I can post it here )in this block I have achieved all the possible routes that are 120 . 5x4x3x2x1=120 . But now , I want to calculate the co2 for all these 120 routes

Comment: I have also got the distances between the cities im km , so that I am able to predict the co2 , on a spread sheet

Comment: So what you have to do is basically a For loop on each thing, creating all the possible paths and then storing in a list once you get to the bottom the amount of co2 it used. What you can do is have a variable that follows each track and adds to that. You could also do a BFS and keep count of amount of co2 instead of distance.